# Python Pandas - Creating a New Dictionary from a Dictionary & Column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

In Pandas, one of my columns "ID_Name" consists of a list of dictionaries with the following format:

```
[{'id': 10, 'name': 'Anna'}, {'id': 15, 'name': 'Bob'}, {'id': 20, 'name': 'Charlie'}, {'id': 25, 'name': 'Donald'} ]
```

Also, I have a column with average incomes called "AVG_INCOME".  Let's say the average income for these four individuals is 100000.

How do I create a new list of dictionaries with the following format:

```
[{'Anna': '100000' }, {'Bob': '100000' }, {'Charlie': '100000' }, {'Donald': '100000'}]
```

Comment: Can you post your DF ?

Answer (score 0):

The way your dataframe was setup:

```
   AVG_INCOME                           ID_Name
0       10000     {u'id': 10, u'name': u'Anna'}
1       10000      {u'id': 15, u'name': u'Bob'}
2       10000  {u'id': 20, u'name': u'Charlie'}
3       10000   {u'id': 25, u'name': u'Donald'}
```

Although it is kind of confusing and inefficient to have dictionaries inside columns in your dataframe. This is how I would make it:

```
import pandas as pd

id_name = [{'id': 10, 'name': 'Anna'},
           {'id': 15, 'name': 'Bob'},
           {'id': 20, 'name': 'Charlie'},
           {'id': 25, 'name': 'Donald'}]

avg_income = [10000] * 4

df = pd.DataFrame(id_name)
df['AVG_INCOME'] = pd.Series(avg_income)
print df
```

Output:

```
   id     name  AVG_INCOME
0  10     Anna       10000
1  15      Bob       10000
2  20  Charlie       10000
3  25   Donald       10000
```

And the line of code you need once you have your dataframe setup

```
print dict(zip(df['name'], df['AVG_INCOME']))
# {'Charlie': 10000L, 'Bob': 10000L, 'Donald': 10000L, 'Anna': 10000L}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `pd.Series.map` with a `lambda` function to extract names.

Then use `dict(zip(keys, values))` construct to create your dictionary.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID_Name': [{'id': 10, 'name': 'Anna'},
                               {'id': 15, 'name': 'Bob'},
                               {'id': 20, 'name': 'Charlie'},
                               {'id': 25, 'name': 'Donald'}],
                   'AVG_INCOME': [10000]*4})

res = dict(zip(df['ID_Name'].map(lambda x: x['name']), df['AVG_INCOME']))

# {'Anna': 10000, 'Bob': 10000, 'Charlie': 10000, 'Donald': 10000}
```

However, you should try and restructure the way you build your dataframe. For example, if you have json input, it should be possible to add a column for `id` and column for `name`. It is inefficient to work with dictionaries with a dataframe.

Answer (score -1):

Try Below, where data is name of your DF

```
dict = dict(zip(data['name'], data['AVG_INCOME']))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ID_Name = [{'id': 10, 'name': 'Anna'},
       {'id': 15, 'name': 'Bob'}, 
       {'id': 20, 'name': 'Charlie'},
       {'id': 25, 'name': 'Donald'} ] 

AVG_INCOME = [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000]

ID_income = [ {ID_Name[i]['name']:AVG_INCOME[i]} for i in range(0, 
               len(ID_Name))]
ID_income
>[{'Anna': 1000}, {'Bob': 1000}, {'Charlie': 1000}, {'Donald': 1000}]
```

Comment: This answer has no reference to `pandas`.

Comment: 1. you did not give your dataframe definition, so I used your lists

Comment: 2. you should point to the line you cannot adapt to your problem if this is the case